# Click icon to flip a button (Login / Sign Up)

Tags: jquery, click

How can I flip a button from Login to Sign Up by clicking on an icon besides it?

Currently I have hover effect on the button itself through which its flipping perfectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fa-chevron-circle-up").click(function() {
    // code to flip button on clicking icon
  });
});
```

```css
.btn_flip:before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotateX(90deg);
}

.btn_flip:hover:before {
  transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0deg);
}

.btn_flip:after {
  content: "Login";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: translateY(0) rotateX(0deg);
}

.btn_flip:hover:after {
  transform: translateY(100%) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
```

Comment: Put the animation and new content in another class like `.btn_flipped` then with jquery add the class `.btn_flipped` when clicked

Comment: So you're saying to toggle classes `.btn_flip` and `.btn_flipped`?

Comment: Yes exactly, that will solve your question